# node js Cannot GET "/router"?

Tags: node.js

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var userService = require('./models/userService');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.get('/movie',userService.getUserById);

app.get('/user',userService.getUserById);
```

I visit "localhost:3000" connect is ok, and "localhost:3000/user" is ok too.
But when I visit "localhost:3000/movie", it give error "Cannot GET /movie".
I really set that route.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart your `app.js` after editing project. So that your route will consider `/movie` also.